# How to filter another at the filtered id in the loop function

Tags: javascript, json, loops

The console.log is : A0004A0003A0001A0005A0004A0002A0001

but I expect the console.log will be: A0004,A0001

Therefore, what missing in this loop function?

```js
var imagedata = [{
    id: "A0007",
    class: "chair house grass"
  },
  {
    id: "A0006",
    class: "car house tree flower grass"
  },
  {
    id: "A0005",
    class: "car house tree flower"
  },
  {
    id: "A0004",
    class: "car tree"
  },
  {
    id: "A0003",
    class: "chair tree flower grass"
  },
  {
    id: "A0002",
    class: "chair house flower"
  },
  {
    id: "A0001",
    class: "car flower"
  },
  {
    id: "A0000",
    class: "chair car house tree flower grass"
  }
];

function myFunction() {


  var o2y = ["1", "all", "0", "1", "all", "0"];
  var o3x = ["chair", "car", "house", "tree", "flower", "grass"];
  var m0x = "";
  var m1x = "";
  for (i = 0; i < o3x.length; i++) {
    m0x = o3x[i];
    for (j = 0; j < imagedata.length; j++) {
      if (o2y[i] == "0") {
        if (imagedata[j].class.search(m0x) < 0) {
          m1x += imagedata[j].id;
          console.log(m1x);
        }
      }
    };
  };
}
myFunction();
```

Comment: Your code do not console log anything.

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated the question. I don't get any logs in console

Comment: I'm sure he just forgot to post the part where he invoked `myFunction`

Comment: @CertainPerformance
because the o2y will change the object if I choose a different input
and click the botton to run myFuntion()

Comment: @RAMHEART can you explain what the filter actually do

Comment: @AhmedYousif  each id have different image url (like "../image/001.jpg') ,
for each object , if the object is choose 0 , the loop will filter from the imagedata haven't this object .Then filter choose 1 have this object . Lastly output result will create <img src="XXX.jpg"> in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code,

```js
var imagedata = [{
      id: "A0007",
      class: "chair house grass"
    },
    {
      id: "A0006",
      class: "car house tree flower grass"
    },
    {
      id: "A0005",
      class: "car house tree flower"
    },
    {
      id: "A0004",
      class: "car tree"
    },
    {
      id: "A0003",
      class: "chair tree flower grass"
    },
    {
      id: "A0002",
      class: "chair house flower"
    },
    {
      id: "A0001",
      class: "car flower"
    },
    {
      id: "A0000",
      class: "chair car house tree flower grass"
    }
    ];

    function myFunction() {


      var o2y = ["1", "all", "0", "1", "all", "0"];
      var o3x = ["chair", "car", "house", "tree", "flower", "grass"];
      var m0x = "";
      var m1x = "";
      var index = [];

      for (i = 0; i < o2y.length; i++) 
        if (o2y[i] == "0") 
          index.push(i);

        for (j = 0; j < imagedata.length; j++) {
          var flag = 0
          for (k = 0; k < index.length; k++) 
            if (imagedata[j].class.search(o3x[index[k]]) < 0) 
              flag++
              
          if(flag == index.length)
            m1x += imagedata[j].id;

        }
        console.log(m1x);
      }
      myFunction();
```